# How do I move an asteroid chunk from my airlock to my refinery?

Tags: spacebase-df-9

I have a bunch of asteroid chunks sitting in my airlock, and I'm starting to run low on minerals.  Instead of mining more asteroids, I'd like to simply move my existing mined asteroid chunks to my refinery, but my miner who doesn't have any mining duties assigned to him doesn't seem to want to cooperate.  How am I supposed to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience is that sooner or later, the miner *does* pick up the asteroid pieces, but task priority in the current version of the game (alpha 1) appears to be a bit buggy.

Sometimes the workers simply decide they have better things to do than performing low priority tasks. A similar example is doors marked for demolishing that are far away from the base. It can take extremely long before anyone decides to perform the task, even in cases where I lock workers up right next to the task I want them to do.

So in short, I believe you are already doing the right thing.

Answer (score -1):

You have to make sure you have at least one person set to a miner. He/She, after a bit, just automatically start collecting.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question.  As I said in my question, I already have at least one person assigned to mining, and there are no asteroids that are designated for mining.